# Exiting a callback function

Tags: javascript, ajax, web, callback, content-management-system

I would like to ask how to exit the callback function given below before ajax call if `valueid2` equals 0

```
callback: function() {
                        console.log('save');
                        console.log($('#re_confirm')[0].checked);
                        var valueid = document.getElementById('idtable').value
                        if(valueid == 0)
                           myFunction();
                        var valueid2 = document.getElementById('idtable').value

                         $.ajax({
                            url : "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/home/update_booking",
                            type: "post",
                            data: {
                                "table_id" : $('#idtable').val(),
                            },
                            success: function(response){
                                   ...
                            }
                       });
      }
```

Please tell me how to exit the callback function.

Comment: Use the `return` statement?

Comment: Hi Daniel B - how to use the return statement - Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by simply using return. This will return the function if valueid2 is 0, and the ajax call will not be run:

```
callback: function() {
    console.log('save');
    console.log($('#re_confirm')[0].checked);
    var valueid = document.getElementById('idtable').value
    if(valueid == 0)
        myFunction();
    var valueid2 = document.getElementById('idtable').value

    if (valueid2 == 0) {
        return; // This return here will end the function
    }

    $.ajax({
    url : "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/home/update_booking",
    type: "post",
    data: {
        "table_id" : $('#idtable').val(),
    },
    success: function(response){
        ...
    }
    });
}
```